# How should i use the Regex on DataFrame to create a new variable using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following Text data below, i have to create a new var call Recommend
using Regular expressions. I tried the following code but ending up with all the rows as "OTHERS".

```
for pat in dt['Text']:
    if re.search('Dropship',str(pat)):
       dt['Recommend'] = 'DROPSHIP'       
    elif re.search('Dispatch',str(pat)):
       dt['Recommend'] = 'DISPATCH'
    elif re.search('Dispatch',str(pat)):
       dt['Recommend'] = 'DISPATCH'
    else:
       dt['Recommend'] = 'OTHERS'
```

Please help me.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TblUy.png)

Answer (score 2):

One-liner with `apply`:

```
df['Recommend'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda x: 'DROPSHIP' if 'Dropship' in x else 'DISPATCH' if 'Dispatch' in x else 'OTHER')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping over the data, you could loop over the options like this:

```
replacements = {'Dropship': 'DROPSHIP', 'Dispatch': 'DISPATCH'}
default_replacement = 'OTHERS'

for pattern, replacement in replacements.items():
    items = dt['Text'].str.contains(pattern)
    dt.loc[items, 'Recommend'] = replacement

df['Recommend'].fillna(default_replacement, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your checks grow, it might be easier to create a function that contains the checks:

```
def get_recommendation(text):
    if re.match('Dropship',str(text)):
       return('DROPSHIP')       
    elif re.search('Dispatch',str(text)):
       return('DISPATCH')
    elif re.search('Dispatch',str(text)):
       return('DISPATCH')
    else:
       return('OTHERS')
```

You can then use `apply()` to use the function:

```
dt['Recommend'] = dt['Text'].apply(lambda x: get_recommendation(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
recommend_list = []
for pat in dt['Text']:
    if 'Dropship' in str(pat):
       recomment_list.append('DROPSHIP')
    elif 'Dispatch' in str(pat):
       recomment_list.append('DISPATCH')
    else:
       recomment_list.append('OTHERS')

dt['Recommend'] = recomment_list
```